# Replace text by leaving specific words

Tags: regex, str-replace

I have the following text (module instantiation in VHDL) multiple times with XXX, YYY and ZZZ as fixed words:

```
my_inst: XXX
 port map ( 
  YYY => my_o,
  ZZZ => my_i 
);
```

I would like to find all the block which instantiate XXX and replace as below.

```
XXX -> BUFF
YYY -> b_o
ZZZ -> b_i
```

The rest of the text should be unchanged.

Again, it is important that YYY is replaced with b_o, only when the XXX module is instantiated and not in other cases.

Thanks!
Sasa

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<key1>\w+):\s*(?<x>XXX)\n*\s*(?<key2>[^(]+?)\s*\(\s*\n*(?=.*?(?<y>YYY)\s=>)(?=.*?(?<z>ZZZ)\s=>)(?:[^(]+)\n*\)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cM0gT4/1)

Output:

```
MATCH 1
key1    [0-8]   `my_inst1`
x   [10-13] `XXX`
key2    [15-23] `port map`
y   [29-32] `YYY`
z   [44-47] `ZZZ`
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I changed it a bit to store only the three I am interested in:
:\s*(?<x>XXX)\n*\s*port\s*\n*map\s*\n*\(\s*\n*(?=.*?(?<y>YYY)\s=>)(?=.*?(?<Z>ZZZ)\s=>)(?:[^(]+)\n*\)

How can I apply it on a file to replace all of them whenever occurred together?